# iframe resize:both broken in FF (is it intended)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have noticed a possible bug in FF where it is impossible to add the CSS resize:both attribute to an iframe, object, embed, and other similar objects. I was wondering if there is an alternate method for simple object resizing, or if this bug can be fixed.

Comment: [Bug 680823](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680823)

Comment: Thanks. The given link has a workaround. +1 for you